# Unable to create a company in Intercom

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, intercom

I'm using this code:

```
Authentication authentication = new Authentication("myAccessToken");
RestClientFactory restClientFactory = new RestClientFactory(authentication);
var _companyClient = new CompanyClient(restClientFactory);

var companyCustomAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "name", "TradingName" },
                { "company_id_str", "5432" },
                { "isoCode", "AU" },
                { "regionCode", "VIC" },
                { "isPropertyManagement", false },
                { "isSales", false },
                { "setupComplete", false },
                { "isSubscription", false },
                { "subscriptionSetupComplete", false },
                { "tradingName", "TradingName" },
                { "ofSMS", false },
                { "ofBankTransfer", false },
                { "ofCommercial", false },
                { "isEmailValidated", true },
                { "isLocked", false },
                { "isOutgoingEmailValidated", true },
                { "banks", "" },
                { "earlyAdopterProgram", false },
                { "propertyCount", 0 }
            };

var company = new Company();
company.company_id = "5432";
company.custom_attributes = companyCustomAttributes;

var createdCompany = _companyClient.Create(company);
```

The `createdCompany` is not null:

[image]

But the company is not showing in the UI:

[image]

Why is the company not showing in the UI?

Intercom API version = 1.4

Intercom.Dotnet.Client version = 2.1.1

Github issue submitted:
https://github.com/intercom/intercom-dotnet/issues/158

Comment: This might be by design according to https://github.com/intercom/intercom-java/issues/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company won't show up if there are no users attached to it.

Comment: That's super annoying.
Why not show the company with a msg displayed somewhere making it obvious that there are no users attached to it.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I had requested them the feature back in 2017, but, i think it doesn't fall in their usecase. What i had done was to not create a company till there were users/leads in the company.